# Linux como Remover Linhas Duplicadas

Tags: linux

Qual comando do terminal Linux para remover linhas duplicadas 
de um arquivo.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a minha favorita seria:

```
cat arquivo.txt | sort | uniq >  novo-arquivo.txt
```

mas isto vai reordenar as linhas. Sem alterarar a ordem:

```
cat arquivo.txt | uniq >  novo-arquivo.txt
```

Comment: É essa mesmo que eu preciso
  --> cat arquivo.txt | sort | uniq >  novo-arquivo.txt

Obrigado